# Access delegate object from a method

Tags: kotlin, delegates

Consider the following Kotlin code:

```
class Derived(n1: String, n2:String) : Teacher by TeacherImp(),Person by PersonImpl(n1, n2) {
     // desire to call method of PersonImp object... possible??
}
```

Is there any way to access the delegate object instances?

Consider if the derived class wants to access a method of a delegate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the delegate(s) into private immutable property(s) - for example:

```
interface Teacher {
    fun sayHelloTeacher() = println("Teacher hello")
}

interface Person {
    fun sayHelloPerson() = println("Person hello")
}

class TeacherImp : Teacher {
    fun sayHelloTeacherImp() = println("TeacherImp hello")
}

class PersonImp(val n1: String, val n2: String) : Person {
    fun sayHelloPersonImp() = println("PersonImp hello $n1 $n2")
}

class Derived private constructor(private val t: TeacherImp, private val p: PersonImp) : 
    Teacher by t, Person by p {

    constructor(n1: String, n2: String) : this(TeacherImp(), PersonImp(n1, n2))

    init {
        sayHelloPerson()
        sayHelloTeacher()
        t.sayHelloTeacherImp()
        p.sayHelloPersonImp()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Derived("first", "second")
}
```

With this implementation the only public constructor is the same as the original, and which calls the private constructor that stores the actual objects.

Note: With reflection it may possible to access them without the extra constructor, but I think this is a straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: It is exactly what I was trying to think of. Making the constructor using the data to instance objects internally in place of inject them as an alternate constructor is the step to allowing this internally instancing pattern, and at the same time enable a more general solution  Thanks